# How can i switch form Circleselecion back to Boxselection in Edit Mode

Tags: edit-mode, selection-tools

[image]First of all I am really new in Blender.
I´m working on a little project but while I was working in Editmode the permanent Selection switched from Box to Circle and don´t know the shortcut to switch again. Maybe I pressed a wrong but I don´t know wich one. Also I don´t mean the Circleselection wich comes when you press C.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the mouse or the keyboard.

**Mouse**

Click and hold the selection to expand the options.

[image]

**Keyboard**

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> then:

- <kbd>B</kbd> for box
- <kbd>C</kbd> for circle
- <kbd>L</kbd> for lasso